# How to find the longest continuous sub-string in a string?

Tags: string, algorithm

For example, there is a given string which is consisted of `1s` and `0s`:

```
s = "00000000001111111111100001111111110000";
```

- What is the efficient way to get the count of longest 1s substring in s? (`11`)
- What is the efficient way to get the count of longest 0s substring in s? (`10`)

I appreciate the question would be answered from an algorithmic perspective.

Comment: You can find your answer in this previous thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458726/find-out-how-long-the-longest-sequence-is-in-a-string

Comment: Not a homework, it is a problem raised in my project. I can use multiple flags to solve this problem, like: int one_start; int one_end; int one_count; int max_one_count; int zero_start; int zero_end; int zero_count; int max_zero_count;  But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to solve it.

Comment: You can never get better than O(n), because you need to scan through the whole input, you can not afford ignoring something from the input in the general case. Also memory can never be improved better than O(1), because there is nothing better than constant, you know. The same statement holds for bitset btw @harold, just the constants will be reduced.

Comment: @harold I would really be interested to see what are the standard practices you refer to. I can tell you that no algorithm analysis can make the complexity go down.

Comment: @harold no way. What you mean is that you assume the bit operations on standard types are constant. For sure, as long as they are of constant length (i.e. 32, or 64 bits). However, for general bitset of arbitrary length no valid analysis assumes constant time of execution. Believe me.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: I'm wondering if it can be done in O(log n) by using a parallel reduction approach (like the parallel sum). But this would need multiple threads or a data parallel processor (a GPU).

Comment: @AsiriRathnayake: I think the complexity in worst case can not be reduced. However, parallel processing will surely reduce the overall time and might reduce the average case complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most straight-forward way is to walk through the bit-string while recording the max lengths for all `0` and all `1` sub-strings. This is of `O (n)` complexity as suggested by others.

If you can afford some sort of a data-parallel computation, you might want to look at parallel patterns as explained [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/parallel-pattern-7-reduce/222000718). Specifically, take a look at [parallel reduction](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/parallel-pattern-7-reduce/222000718). I think this problem can be implemented in `O (log n)` time if you can afford one of those methods.

I'm trying to think of a parallel reduction for this problem:

1. On the first level of the reduction, each thread will process chunks of 8 bit strings (depending on the number of threads you have and the length of the string) and produce a **summary** of the bit string like: `0 -> x, 1 -> y, 0 -> z, ....`
2. On the next level each thread will merge two of these summaries into one, any possible joins will be performed at this phase (basically, if the previous summary ended with a `0` (`1`) and the next summary begins with a `0` (`1`), then the last entry and the first entry of the two summaries can be collapsed into one).
3. On the top level there will be just one structure with the overall summary of the bit string, which you'll have to step through to figure out the largest sequences (but this time they are all in summary form, so it should be faster). Or, you can make each summary structure keep track of the larges `0` and `1` sub-strings, this will make it unnecessary to walk through the final structure.

I guess this approach only makes sense in a very limited scope, but since you seem to be very keen on getting better than `O (n)`...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, could you elaborate the straight-forward way with code a bit?

Comment: @QSortBSearch: That is very trivial, [here's](http://tny.cz/f06863ca/fullscreen.php?hash=4bdd71c81291f1d54f66d06ae15cea83&toolbar=true&linenum=false) a recursive implementation. Don't want to clutter the answer with this code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is one solution I come up with, I'm not sure whether this is bug-free. Correct me if you discover a bug or suggest a better way to do it. Vote it if you agree with this solution. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int s[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0};
    int length = sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]);

    int one_start = 0;
    int one_n = 0;
    int max_one_n = 0;

    int zero_start = 0;
    int zero_n = 0;
    int max_zero_n = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        // Calculate 1s
        if(one_start==0 && s[i]==1){
            one_start = 1;
            one_n++;
        }
        else if(one_start==1 && s[i]==1){
            one_n++;
        }
        else if(one_start==1 && s[i]==0){
            one_start = 0;
            if(one_n > max_one_n){
                max_one_n = one_n;
            }
            one_n = 0;      // Reset 
        }

        // Calculate 0s
        if(zero_start==0 && s[i]==0){
            zero_start = 1;
            zero_n++;
        }
        else if(zero_start==1 && s[i]==0){
            zero_n++;
        }
        else if(one_start==1 && s[i]==1){
            zero_start = 0;
            if(zero_n > max_zero_n){
                max_zero_n = zero_n;
            }
            zero_n = 0;     // Reset 
        }
    }

    if(one_n > max_one_n){
        max_one_n = one_n;
    }
    if(zero_n > max_zero_n){
        max_zero_n = zero_n;
    }

    cout << "max_one_n: " << max_one_n << endl;
    cout << "max_zero_n: " << max_zero_n << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worst case is always O(n), you can always find input which forces the algorithm to check every bit.

But you can probably get average slightly better than that (more simply if you scan just for 0 or 1, not both), because you can skip the length of currently found longest sequence and scan backwards. At the very least this will reduce the constant factor of O(n), but at least with random input, more items also means longer sequences, and thus longer and longer skips. But the difference to O(n) will not be much...